# Aggregating Votes

Tags: signature, voting

Voters may vote 0 or 1. We want to aggregate their votes,  proving runs efficiently $O(n)$ in number of votes but verifying runs $O(1)$ or $O(\log n)$. Voting has to be cryptographically secure - no double voting. Is there a way to return a tally of the votes for 1 and 0?

By secure, we mean we guarantee authenticity, so given the public keys of the voters, anyone can verify that the tally is correct - though they may not need to use all public keys. The votes need not be kept secret.

Some interesting ideas might be to use key shares, to sub-sample a tally of the votes or to use zero knowledge proofs. Not sure how this may be done though.

Comment: Max, can you please edit the information you provided in these comments / in the chat as good as possible into your question? It will help future readers / potential answerers to get a better overview quicker.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73200/discussion-on-question-by-max-chamberlin-aggregating-votes).